# Moving object along a raycast in unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I want to move an object along a ray gradually,

I have the following code so far which moves it in 1 frame to the destination rather than smoothly gliding there.

If I remove the Destroy(projectile.rigidbody2D) line from the end it sort of does it but then bounces around all over the place?

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    void Update () 
{

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (1)) {
            if (Hand.transform.childCount == 1){
            projectile.gameObject.transform.parent = null;

            Ray ray = new Ray(spawn.position,spawn.up);
            RaycastHit hit;

            float shotDistance = shotdistance;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, shotDistance)) {
                shotDistance = hit.distance;
            }
            projectile.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            projectile.rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 0;
            projectile.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * 5);
            projectile.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(projectile.transform.position,ray.direction * shotDistance,shotDistance);
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction * shotDistance,Color.red,1);
            Destroy(projectile.rigidbody2D);

                            }
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private float lerpValue = 0;
public float speed;
private Vector3 startPosition;

private bool isMoving;

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (1))
    {
        if (Hand.transform.childCount == 1)
        {
            lerpValue = 0;
            startPosition = projectile.transform.position;

            projectile.gameObject.transform.parent = null;

            Ray ray = new Ray(spawn.position,spawn.up);
            RaycastHit hit;

            float shotDistance = shotdistance;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, shotDistance) && !isMoving)
            {
    isMoving = true;
                shotDistance = hit.distance;
                //speed = distance / time
                //therefore: time = distance / speed
                float time = shotDistance / speed;

                StartCoroutine(ProjectileMotion(hit.point, time));
            }
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator ProjectileMotion(Vector3 endPosition, float time)
{
    while(lerpValue < time)
    {
        lerpValue += Time.deltaTime;
        projectile.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, lerpValue / time);
    }
isMoving = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joey, I am not at my terminal at the moment, but when I get a chance I will give your code a try. I had a feeling I may need to investigate the Lerp function. Many Thanks,

Comment: Whoops forgot to delete your debug line, you'll have to delete that or change it to DrawLine and use my variables in order for this code to compile; just changed my answer to match

Comment: Hi Joey, this comes up with the error "not all code paths return a value"? Is this due to it being a co-routine? Is there a way to change it to just a void?

Comment: all you have to do is add this line inside of the while statement. yield return null;

Comment: Thanks Joey, the script compiles now and this smooth motion is exactly what I wanted, only issue is that it just moves the object to 0,0,0 rather than following the ray direction / distance, I have tried to solve this myself but am struggling to get anywhere, is it something to do with defining the endPosition in the void Update()?

Comment: Facepalm logic fail, updated answer; the coroutine call should be inside the if block and not invoking every frame. sorry

Comment: Hi joey, thanks for getting back to me again! I have just recompiled with the code you suggested and it is now not moving the object at all, I have looked to see where it is falling down and it is this line: if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, shotDistance)) it is never meeting those criteria so anything in this "if" is not being called?

Comment: Is it something to do with being Physics.Raycast when it should be Physics2D.Raycast? I am searching all over the place here and can't sort this.

Comment: Updated code, try now. Also, I would make a habit of debugging code that doesn't work; E.G. drawing your rays etc so you can see what is actually going on.

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks, I have tried that and it still not entering that if statement, if I put in the following simple check: float shotDistance = shotdistance;
    print (1);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, shotDistance) && !isMoving)
    {
     isMoving = true;
     shotDistance = hit.distance;
     //speed = distance / time
     //therefore: time = distance / speed
     float time = shotDistance / speed;
     print (2);
     StartCoroutine(ProjectileMotion(hit.point, time)); it never gets to print(2);

Comment: That is not very reliable debug that shows you what is actually going on and is useless debug. Try using your Debug class to draw the ray, you are probably putting in a wrong direction ray or perhaps the shotDistance is too small

Comment: Okay if I add this line in before the if statement I can see the correct RayCast if I add it in after I cannot: Debug.DrawRay(spawn.position,spawn.up * shotDistance);